# How do I write a Windows 8 software to run with SYSTEM privileges?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8

I apologize for the bad phrasing in the title, but here's a little more context.

I recently bought a Windows 8 laptop and noticed that Norton was pre-installed and running with SYSTEM level privileges. Thus, it occurred to me that there must be some way for third-party applications to run with SYSTEM privileges.

However, after much googling, I could not figure out whether it was an API call or a registry setting or something else entirely that enabled Norton to do this, so I decided to ask the SO community. How can I write an application that runs with SYSTEM privileges?

Comment: Why do you need to run in that context? If there's a particular problem you want to solve, perhaps you should tell is what the problem is. As it stands now, you're asking "how can I get a key to get into my bank's vault after hours?" The question is why would you want to do that? If you want access to your cash, the answer becomes "Don't get a key; use the ATM!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Services can be configured to run as several different accounts, including `LOCAL SERVICE`, `NETWORK SERVICE`, `SYSTEM`, or any user's account.

Using `SYSTEM` isn't recommended, because any security problem can lead to complete compromise of the machine, but it is available.

This is configured by the *`lpServiceStartName`* parameter of [`CreateService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450.aspx) and/or [`ChangeServiceConfig`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681987.aspx).  Pass a NULL pointer as this parameter of `CreateService`, or `".\\LocalSystem"` to `ChangeServiceConfig`, to use the local system account.

Comment: Is there a way to directly instantiate an Application at SYSTEM privilege level without starting a Service first?

Comment: @merlin: A service is required, but the `Scheduler` service which is preinstalled will start any arbitrary executable with system rights upon request of an administrator.  Configuration of the Microsoft-provided Task Scheduler is a computer administration question, however, and should be discussed on SuperUser rather than SO.

Comment: I cannot appear to run and see GUI applications using Task Scheduler. If I actually write a service myself would I be able to get around the GUI restriction under SYSTEM user?

Comment: You "cannot appear to run"? Why? My spidey sense is tingling here. Something fishy is going on...

Comment: It means I can see the process but I cannot interact with it.

Comment: @merlin2011: No.  The same process should never have both SYSTEM access and a GUI.  Applications such as Norton use two processes, one is a service or driver running with SYSTEM privilege, the other is a GUI running as the user account.  When the GUI is used to request a task that cannot be done by the local user, that is forwarded to the high privilege process.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to run a GUI application as local system.  The best approach is to have both a GUI application (running as the logged-on user) and a service (running as SYSTEM) and have them communicate as needed using any suitable IPC method.  This is probably what Norton is actually doing.

However, it is possible to get a system service to launch an application as SYSTEM in the user's session.  To do this, duplicate the processes security token with `DuplicateTokenEx` and then use [`SetTokenInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `TokenSessionId` option.  This will give you a token in SYSTEM context but in the user's session which you can use to launch an executable.  (There may be additional issues; for example, you might also need to change the permissions on the workstation and desktop.)